# TO_CLOB cutting off report

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, unix, clob

I have a select statement with multiple concats using ||. The statement worked fine until the data became too big so I used TO_CLOB for the select to get around "String concatenation too long" error. The report is now generated but only partially with the data being cut out after 1 rows and the 3rd column of 2nd row.

Here's a short version of my code:

SET pagesize 0
SET echo off
SET feedback off
SET verify off
PROMPT value1, value2, value3, difference
SELECT
TO_CLOB('field1' || ',' || num1 || ',' || num2 || ',' || diff || CHR(10) ||
'field2'  || ',' || num1 || ',' || num2 || ',' || diff || CHR(10) ||
....... (there's about 80 such lines here) .......
)
from table

OUTPUT I'm getting as the report:

value1, value2, value3, difference
field1, num1, num2, diff
field2, num1, num2

and the rest is blank. The rest of about 80 rows are not being generated.

PS: I tested the query on sql developer and it works fine but does this when run in linux.

Please let me know if there's something I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Oracle to concatenate the individual values as `CLOB` data types; wrap each field in `TO_CLOB` (otherwise, it will try to concatenate then as strings and then after concatenating will try to convert the single string to a `CLOB`, which would have already failed if they totalled more than 4000 characters):

```sql
SELECT TO_CLOB( field1 ) || ',' || TO_CLOB( field2 ) || CHR(10)
       || TO_CLOB( field3 ) || ',' || TO_CLOB( field4 ) AS value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( field1, field2, field3, field4 ) AS
SELECT LPAD( 'A', 4000, 'A' ),
       LPAD( 'B', 4000, 'B' ),
       LPAD( 'C', 4000, 'C' ),
       LPAD( 'D', 4000, 'D' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE                                       |
> | ------------------------------------------- |
> | AAA ... x4000 ... AAA,BBB ... x4000 ... BBB |
> | CCC ... x4000 ... CCC,DDD ... x4000 ... DDD |
> ```

It may be sufficient just to convert the first value in the list to a `CLOB`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CLOB( field1 ) || ',' || field2 || CHR(10)
       || field3 || ',' || field4 AS value
FROM   table_name;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b285bc6e04ea3d717eb8fb2cd520eca)*

Comment: I did what you mentioned but it doesn't change anything with the report. It's still being cut off. I tried setting the longchunksize to 50000 but that doesnt help either.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to generate a CSV file from the command line, I would highly recommend trying out [SQLcl](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqlcl-downloads.html). It works just like SQLPlus, but has much more functionality similar to what you would find in SQL Developer but through a command line interface. It is Java based so you will need at least Java 8.

By setting the `sqlformat` option, you can quickly generate a CSV file with ease. Since it is 99% compatible with SQLPlus commands, you can still spool and set whatever other format options you need. You can see from the example that it will even properly escape `"` as `""` if there is a `"` in the columns being selected to generate a properly structured CSV file.

**Edit**: Andrew Sayer pointed out in the comments that this functionality is also available in the normal SQLPlus client since client version 12.2 using the `set markup csv on` command.

Here is a quick demonstration:

```sql
SQL> SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL + 1 AS next_level, 'Level: "' || LEVEL || '"' AS level_text
  2        FROM DUAL
  3  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

   LEVEL    NEXT_LEVEL     LEVEL_TEXT
________ _____________ ______________
       1             2 Level: "1"
       2             3 Level: "2"
       3             4 Level: "3"
       4             5 Level: "4"
       5             6 Level: "5"
       6             7 Level: "6"
       7             8 Level: "7"
       8             9 Level: "8"
       9            10 Level: "9"
      10            11 Level: "10"

10 rows selected.

SQL> set sqlformat csv

SQL> SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL + 1 AS next_level, 'Level: "' || LEVEL || '"' AS level_text
  2        FROM DUAL
  3  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;

"LEVEL","NEXT_LEVEL","LEVEL_TEXT"
1,2,"Level: ""1"""
2,3,"Level: ""2"""
3,4,"Level: ""3"""
4,5,"Level: ""4"""
5,6,"Level: ""5"""
6,7,"Level: ""6"""
7,8,"Level: ""7"""
8,9,"Level: ""8"""
9,10,"Level: ""9"""
10,11,"Level: ""10"""

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: SQL*Plus also has this functionality since the 12.2 client:
`set markup csv on`

Comment: Wow! Didn't know! Thanks for the info!